# How to make nested call with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've below code in JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#key_verify").click(function () {
    $("#errrmsg").html("<img src=\"/images/shim.gif\"/>");
    if($.trim($("#key").val()).length != 0){
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    async : true,
    url : "/issuekey?key="+$("#key").val(),
    success : function(data) {
      var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      if(json_obj === undefined || json_obj == null){
      }else{
        if(json_obj.result == "true"){
            top.location.href="/register"
        }else{
            $("#errrmsg").html(invalid_key);
        }
      }
    },
    error : function(data) {
      $("#errrmsg").html(invalid_product_key); 
    }
  });
  }
});
```

}

How can I invoke above code in below lines so that when user hits enter key, it should make a call on enter key as well??

```
$("#key_verify").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
        ??????
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want your first function/events to be called if the `#key_verify` is clicked **or** pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function you are passing to the `click` handler into a named function like so:

```
var verify = function(e) {
   // your current anonymous function
   $("#errrmsg").html("<img src=\"/images/shim.gif\"/>");

   // ... the rest of your function
}
```

Then pass it as an argument into your event handlers:

```
$("#key_verify").click( verify );
$("#key_verify").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
        verify( e );
    }
});
```